# viewing a client-side pdf in a jsp

Tags: jsp, pdf, client, embed

How do I show a client-side pdf (i.e. a preview of a file on their hard-drive) in a jsp?

I can embed a server-side pdf:

```
<embed src="fw4.pdf" name="preview_image" width=400 height=800
border=0 type="application/pdf" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.adobe.com/downloads/">
```

I can preview a client-side img:

```
<img src="file:\\\\C:\\temp\\IMG_9990_w.jpg" name=preview_image height="600" width="600">
```

How do I preview a client-side pdf?

I have tried using iframes, embed tags (with the path similar to one in the img tag above), etc., etc..  Any suggestions?

Comment: just find a question on how to donwload files with jsp/servlets. PDF is handled by the client automatically then.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have done the search and I am able to do show previews of regular images but I have had no luck with the pdfs.  The client is not handling it properly.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Just define its path in `embed src` the same way as you did for `img src`.</strike>

---

**Update**: OK, that didn't work. The case which you have there is also pretty rare though. Normally PDF's and all other embedded stuff is served by the webserver, not loaded from the client's local disk file system. Why this requirement? Is it an intranet webapplication which is accessing some shared network drive which is supposed to be available on all client machines?

If that is indeed the case, then I'd attach that network disk on the webserver as well and just use a servlet to stream the bytes unchanged from that disk to the HTTP response and then let the `embed src` point to that servlet.

If that is not the case, then I really don't see any sensible reasons to design your webpage like that, or it must be for some specific personal purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  It just shows an empty square for Chrome, IE and Mozilla.

Comment: This is a requirement for an upload feature (not my choice ;)).   The users on the client are going to be editing a pdf on their machine (not super users, just regular users).  They then want to upload it to the server.  They are going to select the files to upload from a picker for which it would be nice if they could see a preview.  If it were up to me I would skip this feature all together and tell them to use the file previews provided for free by the OS.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest to create a client side UI application which you embed on your webpage, like an applet.

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to do that.  I was hoping to piggy-back (user validation, encryption, etc., etc.) on the jsp web-application already in that system but that is not going to happen.